Execute a last line of code when the user closes the console window
If we run a Python program in a console on Windows (python myscript.py), is there a possibility to run a last line of code when the user clicks on the "X" top-right button of the console window?
I already tried something similar to  Executing a function when the console window closes?:
import atexit, time, subprocess

def bye():
    subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")

atexit.register(bye)
print('Sleeping now...')
time.sleep(10)    # click on the top right "X" button of the console window: notepad doesn't start

but it doesn't work: notepad doesn't start.
PS: not a duplicate of Executing a function when the console window closes? because my question is specific to Windows which shows a specific behaviour.

You could run a watchdog process. You start the watchdog on startup and it just sits there waiting for the parent process to terminate in order to act on it. That said, what are you really trying to achieve? This sounds a bit like an XY Problem to me.

Given that this is Windows-specific, you could set up a handler to detect the user closing the console along these lines:
import subprocess, time, ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, BOOL

def py_handler(ctrl_type):
    if ctrl_type == 2:
        subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
    return True

handler = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, DWORD)(py_handler)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, True)

print('Sleeping now...')
time.sleep(10)  

In the function 'py_handler' I have set the condition that ctrl_type == 2, which corresponds to the user closing the console. There are other options e.g. responding to Ctrl-C etc - see here for more options

Nice! Do you have an idea why atexit is too late to be able to launch notepad.exe, whereas in your solution, your script has time to launch notepad.exe before being killed by the window-closing operation?

I'm assuming the direct closing of the console does not provide a signal that is handled by Python, as opposed to things like calling sys.exit() or hitting Ctrl-C. If I'm right, it wouldn't matter what your 'bye' function contained.
